# Does a class hold references to its field objects?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I am a bit confused GC aspect when it comes to the instance variables, especially fields.

So, if an object holds references to its field objects, these won't be eligible for garbage collection until the object itself is. Since [Threads are GC roots](https://www.dynatrace.com/resources/ebooks/javabook/how-garbage-collection-works/) and every object must have been created on some Thread only, [thread won't let go of any objects created on it](https://www.dynatrace.com/resources/ebooks/javabook/how-garbage-collection-works/) and the entire object hierarchy from a Thread shall remain for a considerable time before getting garbage collected.

On the other hand, if an object lets go of the field objects, calling a getter for these objects will end up in returning null later.

So, what are the facts here?

---

**Clarification for "field objects"(as asked in comments)**

- By field objects I mean, the field members of an object that are themselves objects

---

**Edit 2: A bit more elaboration**

So, you see Threads are execution units having representation in memory through the Thread object instance. Any code execution that is happening anywhere is happening on some Thread.

How would this execution happen?

Well, through the execution of some code in a method. What would that make this object created?

- A Local variable

And, that would make it a GC root.

Btw, for a method call, there is a stack for that particular call and this is what I have been referring to here.

Comment: What is "field object"? Do you understand the difference between stack and heap?

Comment: Why do you think that threads won't let go of any objects created on them?  Just because an object was created on a thread doesn't mean there's still a reference from that thread to that object.

Comment: @LouisWasserman : Any object you create on Thread shall get created on a stack. These local variables are GC roots as per https://www.dynatrace.com/resources/ebooks/javabook/how-garbage-collection-works/   Thtat's why.

Comment: @PM77-1 : Clarification given in the edit

Comment: @PM77-1 : Yes, I know that any object is created on heap(dynamic allocation) and local variables are created on stack(references on stack and actual objects on heap)

Comment: @LouisWasserman : I added more explanation in case of any confusion

Comment: They get created on the stack, but they don't necessarily _stay_ on the stack.  If they are still on the stack, then they're still needed.  The objects stay only as long as some thread needs them.

Comment: @LouisWasserman :  Yes, but still the question remains, does an object have a reference to its member field objects?

Comment: Yes, naturally.

Answer (score 0):

It ain't so simple as @louis-wasserman said - *"Yes, naturally"* or for that matter not that *natural*..(?)

I investigated some more and found the answer on...where you would expect it probably - **[Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html)**

> 2.7. Representation of Objects
>
> The Java Virtual Machine does not mandate any particular internal
> structure for objects.
>
> In some of Oracle’s implementations of the Java Virtual Machine, a
> reference to a class instance is a pointer to a handle that is itself
> a pair of pointers: one to a table containing the methods of the
> object and a pointer to the Class object that represents the type of
> the object, **and the other to the memory allocated from the heap for
> the object data**.

Yes, that settles it. Even though, JLS doesn't mandate on the internal structure of an `java.lang.Object`, it would be likely that a structure similar to Oracle's JVM might be used.

This has bigger implication that you might think. Imagine a very *heavy* object holding one very bulky member field object. Hmmm...a `Bitmap` maybe. A Bitmap of 10MB and the other object simply holds the image's title:

*bulky_object = {bitmap, title}*

If you create up this object as a local variable inside a method inside a nested scope(for example's sake), the container object is eligible for garbage collection after the scope gets over but if you decide to hold a reference to the bitmap(the field) object after the scope, the containing object won't have been collected *fully*:

```
void someMethod(){
        
        // Outer block of the method
        bitmap_ref;
        
        // Nested block starts
        {
            some_object = new some_object();
            // Hold a ref to the bitmap
            bitmap_ref = some_object.bitmap;
        }
        // Nested block has ended. some_object is eligible for GC and is not accessible as a GC root
        // anymore
        
        // bitmap_ref shall remain available alive and well here as we are holding a ref to it
        // Also, some_object garbage collection may have happened leaving bitmap_ref alive
    }
```

This would seem like an object leak here.